# unwanted space between navigation bar and div(red color)

Tags: html, css

I am getting an unwanted space like this between red color div and header
my html is i've give 0 value for margin and padding for html and body.But still there's a problem please help

```
 <header>

    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-fixed navbar-inverse">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle nav-button">

            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Example</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-ul">

           <li id="tech" class="nav-list">         <a href="#">home</a></li>
           <li id="politics" class="nav-list">     <a href="#">careers</a></li>
           <li id="crime" class="nav-list">        <a href="#">about</a></li>
           <li id="business" class="nav-list">     <a href="#">contact</a></li>


        </ul>

    </div>

    </nav>

</header>

<section class="frontpage">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5">

              </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
<section class="ghi">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5">

              </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

and css is i've also tried giving 0 padding and margins for div and header

```
       body,html {
          margin:0;
         padding:0;
          }
       header{
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         }  
      .frontpage{
          background:red;
       height:200px;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       }
      .ghi{
         background:blue;
          height:220px;

        }
```

Comment: Are you compiling this output from multiple files? If so, you might need to remove the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which pretty much translates to an empty line in most browsers. The quickets way would be changing file encoding from _UTF-8 with signature_ to _UTF8 **without** signature_.

Comment: removed it but still not working..

Comment: I'd inspect the element in the browser (right click on problematic whitespace, _inspect element_) to see what's up with it.

Comment: In elements , when I'm hovering at div with classes "nav" and "navbar-default" .The white space is getting highlighted..

Comment: What color is it highlighted with, if I may ask? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: its white , i've also seen that in other bootstrap templates  . So, Im thinking its becoz of bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it

```
.navbar{
       margin-bottom: 0!important;
    }
```

```css
body,html {}
header{}  
.frontpage{
 background:red;
   height:200px;       
}
.ghi{
  background:blue;
height:220px;
}

.navbar{
   margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<header>

    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-fixed navbar-inverse">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle nav-button">

            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Example</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-ul">

           <li id="tech" class="nav-list">         <a href="#">home</a></li>
           <li id="politics" class="nav-list">     <a href="#">careers</a></li>
           <li id="crime" class="nav-list">        <a href="#">about</a></li>
           <li id="business" class="nav-list">     <a href="#">contact</a></li>


        </ul>

    </div>

    </nav>

</header>

<section class="frontpage">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5">

              </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
<section class="ghi">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5">

              </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: not working . i'm using bootstrap is there a  problem because of that?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the Browser is adding default margins to the `ul` Elements. Add this style to your css and it should fix the issue:

```
ul.nav { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: tried it but not working... and  also tried.nav-ul { 
 margin-bottom: 0; 
 }

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else have same problem. I fixed it based on reading https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ in my case just added this line margin-bottom: -10px;