# Why space is appearing between nav and div (background image)?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am converting existing website into responsive website. I am using bootstrap and doing it for the first time. I am getting the space between nav and div. What is the reason behind it? I am new to Bootstrap.

[image]

Markup:

```html
<div class="container-fullwidth example2">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button 
                    type="button" 
                    class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#navbar2">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com">
                    <img src="images/layout/check.png" 
                        style="width:451px;height:36px;" 
                        class="img-responsive" 
                        alt="dubaiexporters.com"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>                           
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" 
                            class="dropdown-toggle" 
                            data-toggle="dropdown" 
                            role="button" 
                            aria-expanded="false">Exhibitions 
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Trade fairs in U.A.E</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trade fairs worldwide</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Add Your Event</a></li>             
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Memberships</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div id="backgroundimage"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#backgroundimage {
    background-image: url("https://d12dkjq56sjcos.cloudfront.net/pub/media/wysiwyg/Dubai-Skyline-Burj-Al-Arab-Big-Bus-Tours-01.17.jpg");
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; 
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Don't give height, set height to auto and width 100%.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me..

```
.navbar{
       margin-bottom: 0!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Bootstrap sets 20px margin below to the `.navbar`

```
.navbar {
position: relative;
min-height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

I hope following image snap will help you to find out the issue.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/euqV9.png

You should over write that margin property with 0px like below

```
.navbar {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its near impossible to anyone to give you an answer that really solve your issue... because they can not debug / check the css of your pages - and even if some one do, they can not know if its work for sure until you check it - and so on...

But then I think this ["**give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime**"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

and I will give you a tutorial on how to find your self why this margin there.

The main idea is to use the browser tools to inspect your page and the on it css, and change it live to find the reason... look on this pages for a start up tutorial on that

[Inspect and Edit Pages and Styles](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/)

[Get Started With Viewing And Changing CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/)

Comment: well...it is possible.I have provided here everything that is needed.....Anyways...i found out the ans.....Thanks to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173890/unwanted-space-between-navigation-bar-and-divred-color...

Comment: @chetankambli from what I see on the answers the `.navbar` is the one you need to change - and this is not on your question, so you get an answer from their experience... that is a good guess...